# Can Hyperledger Fabric support asset mutation?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

In Hyperledger Fabric, is it possible to transfer an asset into another asset type, combine assets, and divide assets into other types?

All of the Hyperledger Fabric fabric proof-of-concept videos from IBM show how to transfer an asset, say a car, like such:

`creation -> manufacture -> dealership -> leaser -> junk yard`

However; a car starts off as individual parts, and those parts start off as raw material. Also, a car can have it's radio replaced. And finally, when a car is sold to a junk yard it's metal could melted down and re-created into a raw asset.

Are there API's in Hyperledger Fabric to handle these types of transactions?

Or maybe, a better way of asking the question is:

- Can the Hyperledger Fabric transaction table handle these types of transactions?

Or maybe, a better way of asking the question is:

- Can I write chaincode that combine assets, divide assets, and/or transfer an asset into another asset type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Management of assets/state is exclusively the application code's responsibility (chaincode). The chaincode and Fabric APIs are solely for interacting with chaincode, the ledger and consensus, etc. There is no native asset type system.

So in answer to your questions:

*Are there API's in Hyperledger Fabric to handle these types of transactions?* **No**.
*Can the Hyperledger Fabric transaction table handle these types of transactions?* **Yes**.
*Can I write chaincode that combine assets, divide assets, and/or transfer an asset into another asset type?* **Yes**.

Comment: As you tagged 'Hyperledger Composer' in your question: you can use Hyperledger Composer to model the varying asset types. And model the transactions and indeed events that define what updates take place to existing Assets, or when / at what point there is the genesis (creation) of a new Asset 'type' and transitional state of an 'old' (ie as part of the end-to-end lifecycle you defined). And yet, still have a history of a previous Asset form ('type' as you define it) or forms.